# ServiceStack ambiguous conflict in Servicestack.Core

Tags: servicestack, system.reflection

Servicestack.Core

I need get property from reflection:

```
PropertyInfo property = branch.GetType().GetProperty("Prop");
```

but I get this conflict:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'ServiceStack.PlatformExtensions.GetProperty(System.Type, string)' and
>   'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.GetProperty(System.Type, string)'

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the package reference to `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions` or use the fully qualified method `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.GetProperty()`